# Access token expiration

Tags: access-token

Is there a way to change the expiration of the of the access token from 1hr to something less?
I initially thought that the value in the exp claim of the JWT claim set would set the expiration of of the access token but that wasn't so. 
The reason for my inquiry is that we're creating a Server to Server app that will use Google's provisioning api to update our employees' account.  An admin account for our domain will be created and will be used to send out a short request such as changing names and/or password.  I would like the access token to be short-lived as possible so that it will be useless if it is compromised.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no a way to change the expiration time of an access token, but what you can do is revoke it when your client is done with it as described in: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/disconnect

So:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=<access_token>
```

Comment: I tried revoking the token by using that url but it didn't seem to work.  I received a status code of 200 which is suppose to mean a successful process a according to this [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) but  when I check the status of the token here (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=<access_token>), the token is still active.  I also verified that the token is active by using it to update one of our employee's account.

Comment: Since our application is accessing user data, I followed the "Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account" steps in here: [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)
Do I need to setup something else in our account to be able to revoke tokens?

Comment: the docs say `**Note**: Following a successful revocation response, it may take some time before the revocation has full effect.` so perhaps wait a bit?

Comment: No luck.  The token stayed active until an hour later when it expired.

Comment: seems to work for me, first time `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, second time revoking the same access token `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` `{
  "error" : "invalid_token",
  "error_description" : "Token expired or revoked"}`

Comment: I use a standard Google Account Login flow using OpenID Connect to obtain an access token as a part of that as described here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: Here's a doc with print-screens of what's going on with mine.  I'm wondering if an access token that's created in a Delegate Service Account can not be revoke. 
[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B40iqeM58pd5SktaR0o5a29BRnc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: must have to do with how you got the access token indeed; when I try the same sequence with my access token, the 2nd introspection call results in `{
 "error": "invalid_token",
 "error_description": "Invalid Value"
}`

Comment: Thanks, Hans.  I will dig some more to see why mine is not revoking.